# Function return type not enforced

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, polymorphism, type-coercion

I would be very thankful if someone patient enough explained to me the situation below. It seems to me as if Haskell were ready to perform some kind of integral type coercion when returning a value from a function. On the other hand, I have read that Haskell does never convert a type implicitly.

If I type in GHCi:

```
> import Data.Word
> let t :: (Integer, Word32); 
      t = let { y = fromIntegral (-1)     -- line breaks added for readability
              ; y' :: Integer 
              ; y' = fromIntegral y } in (y', y)
```

GHCi tells me later that `t = (-1,4294967295)`. But if I constrain the local `y` type specifically to `Word32`:

```
> let t :: (Integer, Word32); 
      t = let { y :: Word32
              ; y = fromIntegral (-1)     -- line breaks added for readability
              ; y' :: Integer
              ; y' = fromIntegral y } in (y', y)
```

GHCi will tell me that `t = (4294967295,4294967295)`.

I thought that if `t`'s type is stated explicite as `(Integer, Word32)`, GHCi will conclude that `y' :: Integer` and `y :: Word32` since the function result is `(y', y)`. Then, the type definition `y :: Word32` would be completely unnecessary.

This all started when I tried to write a function to "safely" convert between Integral class members - e.g. Int -> Word32. That function was meant to return `Just 1` when passed `1` and `Nothing` when passed `-1`.

A short search through SO and internet overall didn't provide me with any explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought that if `t`'s type is stated explicite as `(Integer, Word32)`, GHCi will conclude that `y' :: Integer` and `y :: Word32` since the function result is `(y', y)`.

No, it does not infer anything about the types of `y'` and `y`. It just checks whether they are compatible with the expected type. A simpler example<sup>1</sup>:

```
x = -1

y :: Integer
y = x

y' :: Word32
y' = x
```

Which type does `x` have? It's neither `Integer` nor `Word32`. It's the [type of literals](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-typeclasses/#_literals):

```
x :: Num a => a
x = fromInteger (-1 :: Integer)
```

And `Num a => a` is compatible both with the usage as an `Integer` in `y` and as a `Word32` in `y'`. It doesn't matter how `x` is used, the type of `x` is determined only by how the term is defined.

---

To explain your results, remember referential transparency - we can just replace the variables with their definition:

```
t = let y = fromIntegral (-1)
        y' = (fromIntegral y) :: Integer
    in (y', y) :: (Integer, Word32)
```

expands to

```
t = ( (fromIntegral (fromIntegral (-1))) :: Integer -- nothing says Word32 here
    , fromIntegral (-1)
    ) :: (Integer, Word32)
```

whereas the second

```
t = let y = (fromIntegral (-1)) :: Word32
        y' = (fromIntegral y) :: Integer
     in (y', y) :: (Integer, Word32)
```

expands to

```
t = ( (fromIntegral ( (fromIntegral (-1)) :: Word32 )) :: Integer
    , (fromIntegral (-1)) :: Word32
    ) :: (Integer, Word32)
```

<sub>1: I hope the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) doesn't mess with us here. Can anyone more knowledgeable confirm that it doesn't apply to `x` (or under what circumstances)?</sub>

Comment: Isn't it puzzling that `(fromIntegral : b -> c) . (fromIntegral : a -> b) : a -> c` doesn't lead to a type error? How is the "intermediate" type `b` picked given that it is neither determined by the input nor the output?

Comment: @gallais Very good catch! The solution is that [there's a special case for numeric classes](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) which allows the compiler to default `Num b => b` without an explicit type annotation, and the default `default` is `Integer`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The result depends on the `-X[No]MonomorphismRestriction` option. By default, the `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` option is used in GHCi, so GHCi inferred a type for `y :: Num a => a`. And in the expression `fromIntegral y` it instantiated as `Integer` (by default instance for `Num` class), in the expression `(y', y)` it instantiated as `Word32`. When you explicitly specified type of `y`, the variable `y` was `Word32` in all the expression.

If you run the command `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction`, all variants will get the same result.